# DataContractSerialization of generic type hierarchies

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, serialization, datacontractserializer

The following program, which tries to serialize and then deserialize an object of a generic type from a hierarchy, fails with the error listed below the code.

How do I make it work?

#### Code:

```
[DataContract]
[KnownType(nameof(GetKnownTypes))]
public abstract class Base<T>
{
    private static Type[] GetKnownTypes()
    {
        return new[] {typeof(DerivedA<T>)};
    }
}


[DataContract]
public class DerivedA<T> : Base<T>
{
    [DataMember]
    public T Foo { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    private static void Main()
    {
        // This works fine
        var foo = new DerivedA<string> { Foo = "foo" };
        var xml = Serialize(foo);
        var foo2 = Deserialize<DerivedA<string>>(xml);
        Console.WriteLine(foo2.Foo); // foo

        // This throws the exception below
        // (from serializer.ReadObject() in the Deserialize method)
        var foo3 = Deserialize<Base<string>>(xml);
    }

    private static string Serialize<T>(T o)
    {
        string result = null;
        var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(o.GetType());
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            serializer.WriteObject(stream, o);
            stream.Position = 0;

            var reader = new StreamReader(stream);
            result = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
        return result;
    }

    private static T Deserialize<T>(string xml)
    {
        var result = default(T);
        var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(T));
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            var writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
            writer.Write(xml);
            writer.Flush();
            stream.Position = 0;

            result = (T)serializer.ReadObject(stream);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

#### The exception:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: Error in line 1 position 139. Expecting element 'BaseOfstring' from namespace 'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ConsoleApplication7'.. Encountered 'Element'  with name 'DerivedAOfstring', namespace 'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ConsoleApplication7'.
  at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer.InternalReadObject(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, Boolean verifyObjectName, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver)
  at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.ReadObjectHandleExceptions(XmlReaderDelegator reader, Boolean verifyObjectName, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver)
  at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.ReadObject(XmlDictionaryReader reader)
  at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.ReadObject(Stream stream)
  at ConsoleApplication7.Program.Deserialize[T](String xml) in c:\users\tly01\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\ConsoleApplication7\ConsoleApplication7\Program.cs:line 65
```

The most interesting part of the message makes it pretty clear what went wrong:

> Expecting element 'BaseOfstring' from namespace . Encountered 'Element'  with name 'DerivedAOfstring', namespace .

Sure enough, `xml` in the main method above is this (with whitespace added):

```
<DerivedAOfstring
    xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ConsoleApplication7"
    xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Foo>foo</Foo>
</DerivedAOfstring>
```

I realize that I somehow have to make the serializer aware of my type hierarchy, but I've tried a lot of different variants of the `KnownType` attribute in the listing above, and none of them have been fruitful. What's the correct way to make this work?

Answer (score 3):

What you need to do is to always serialize and deserialize your derived type with a `DataContractSerializer` [constructed using identical `Type` arguments](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404901.aspx).  You are trying to use `DerivedA<T>` for serialization and `Base<T>` for deserialization.  This inconsistency causes the problem you are seeing.

The reason this is happening is as follows.  In general, there are two conventional ways a polymorphic type can get serialized to XML:

- The element name can be changed to represent the derived type.  With `XmlSerializer`, this is supported via the [`[XmlElement(elementName, subType)]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cz6bdh5z.aspx) attribute among others.
- The element can assert its type explicitly using the standard [`{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}type`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#xsi_type) attribute, usually shortened to `xsi:type`.  `XmlSerializer` supports this mechanism via [`[XmlInclude(subType)]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlincludeattribute.aspx) attributes.  `DataContractSerializer` supports this through the [`KnownTypeAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730167.aspx).

The fact that `DataContractSerializer` uses the second mechanism is what is causing your problem.  When you serialize an instance of your derived class, the derived class contract name is emitted for the root element name.  But when you serialize an instance of your derived class **as an instance of its base class**, the base class contract name is used with an additional `xsi:type`.  To see this, refactor your code as follows:

```
    private static string Serialize<T>(T o)
    {
        return Serialize(o, null);
    }

    private static string Serialize<T>(T o, DataContractSerializer serializer)
    {
        string result = null;
        serializer = serializer ?? new DataContractSerializer(o.GetType());
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            serializer.WriteObject(stream, o);
            stream.Position = 0;

            var reader = new StreamReader(stream);
            result = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Now if you do:

```
var xml = Serialize(foo);
Debug.WriteLine(xml);
```

You will see

```
<DerivedAOfstring 
 xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Question37284138" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
     <Foo>foo</Foo>
</DerivedAOfstring>
```

But if you do

```
var baseXml = Serialize(foo, new DataContractSerializer(typeof(Base<string>)));
Debug.WriteLine(baseXml);
```

You will see:

```
<BaseOfstring i:type="DerivedAOfstring"
 xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Question37284138" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Foo>foo</Foo>
</BaseOfstring>
```

Notice the difference?  It means that the former cannot be deserialized using a `DataContractSerializer(typeof(Base<string>))`.  But if you *serialize* using 
`DataContractSerializer(typeof(Base<string>))` then deserialization will work - and correctly construct an instance of `DerivedA<string>` thanks to the presence of the `xsi:type` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

This all looks totally by design.

First, why do you bring the generic part here? It does not seem to have anything to do with the problem.

Let's make this simple:

You have a base class:

```
[DataContract]
[KnownType(typeof(MyDerived))]
public abstract class MyBase
{
    ...
}
```

And a successor:

```
[DataContract]
public class MyDerived : MyBase
{
    ...
}
```

Then you serialize an instance of class `MyDerived`. And then you try to deserialize it but you are not telling the `DataContractSerializer` about the type it should expect to see, from your code:

```
var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(T));
```

where you have `T` equal to `MyBase`. So basically you try to deceive the `DataContractSerializer` i.e. you are telling it should expect to get an instance of `MyBase` which is impossible and it sees metadata for an instance of `MyDerived` in xml. Keep in mind, `DataContractSerializer` does not see the full assembly name, so the xml node type `MyDerived` is not enough for `DataContractSerializer` to do anything. It has no right to guess about the type from the `KnownType` in this situation.

Look here: [DataContractSerializer Constructor (Type)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404901(v=vs.110).aspx)
It clearly says:

> type
>   Type: System.Type
>   The type of the instances that are serialized or deserialized.

`KnownType` does not work here. You have to explicitly specify the type you are deserializing that has to match the type you used in serialization.

You can try to workaround the problem if you serialize the `MyDerived` instance using the `MyBase` metadata in the first place:

```
var xml = Serialize((MyBase)foo);
```